# I want know about view which is in my screenshot

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want show view like in my screen shot on my app ..anyone please tell me how to show this type of view ..if you watch my screenshot it is batter to understand actually am not working in this type of view before this ...[image]

Comment: which part of the screenshot? there are many views on that screenshot

Comment: First of all thanks for your comment ...i want add HTML , CSS, JS  all code view to my app in which user can run

Comment: Such a widget does not exist.

Comment: is there any way other way to make

Comment: Yes. You can make it yourself, with the building blocks flutter provides. Probably a few thousand lines of code. As a starter, search for "flutter rich text editor"

Comment: okay thanks for information